# How to read a text file in an Angular 8 unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I've have written a angular 8 application and planning to write unit test. Especially I need to test a file parser I have developed.

How do I read a text file, which is my golden model, from a unit test?

Comment: Angular tests run in a browser, there are no fs in a browser, import a JSON constant if you need to get the data from your file

Comment: Please explain, my file is not JSON.

Comment: Post your file first please

Comment: My file is a kicad schematic file, quite big. I post it as soon I am returning to my computer.

Comment: Angular is a client side framework, so the tests run in a browser environment, and in a browser environment there are not a filesystem, so you cant use readFileSync from node which is the method you would use to read a file in a server

Comment: I understand that, but most apps today, supports uploads. For example user pictures. I believed it was possible.

Comment: What you can do is mock a http request which retrieves the content of the file, however if a test depends of an external file the reliability is compromised, you need to test the implementation of your component / service / directive or whatever, but the test should not depend of external factors which are not related to the code being tested

Answer (score 3):

**Assumptions:**

- You're using *Jasmine* with *Karma*.
- The method to be tested is `KicadReader#read(url: string, dataHandler: DataHandler)`,  `DataHandler` being some custom `interface` or `class`.
- Your test file is `src/app/shared/services/reader/kicad/test.sch`.

This could be done with `XMLHttpRequest` as follows:

```
it('#read should supply Kicad file content', (done) => {

    // given
    const filePath = 'src/app/shared/services/reader/kicad/test.sch';
    const request: XMLHttpRequest = createRequest(filePath );

    request.onload = r => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([request.response]));

        // when
        kicadReader.read(url, dataHandler);
    };

    dataHandler.onData = data => {

        // then
        expect(data).toBe('expected data');
        done();
    };

    // trigger
    request.send(null);
});

function createRequest(filePath: string): XMLHttpRequest {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'base/' + filePath, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // maybe also 'text'
    return request;
};
```

To make this work, *Karma* needs to be told to serve the test file (see http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/files.html). To do so, add the following to your `karma.config.js`:

```
files: [
      { pattern: 'src/app/shared/services/reader/kicad/test.sch', included: false, watched: false, served: true }
]
```